# Calculate work hours

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to calculate hours for regular time, overtime and double time with the cells in photo.

[image: 2]

This is the hours rule our employees must follow.

[image: 3]

I'm having a hard time trying to have the cells do an overflow for the over time/double time hours (I know it's possible because I accidently did it before). The max for reg should be 8, any more should overflow to the next cell and that should also have a max of 4 hours with the over flow to the next cell.

[image: 1]
This is how the cells should look

I just put the numbers, no functions. I need the formulas for cells G12, H12 and I12.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried

Comment: =(F12-D12)*24      I'm just getting the total

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Comment: I put another photo please read the EDIT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't describe how to treat your Lunch flag, so I ignored it. But if you need to subtract time due to a Y/N flag, then some of these formulas will need to be adjusted. Also, you didn't describe how to show non-even hour calculations, so I'm using decimals here. Lastly, you didn't mention if time in/out could overlap days. If so, you'll need to MOD these formulas too.

There are several ways to achieve this, including this method:

**Cell H2 Formula** (to get total hours worked):

```
     =((D2-B2)*1440)/60
```

**Cell E2 Formula** (regular hours worked):

```
     =MIN(8,H2)
```

**Cell F2 Formula** (OT hours worked):

```
    =IF(H2>E2,MIN(4,H2-E2),0)
```

**Cell G2 Formula** (DT hours worked):

```
    =H2-SUM(E2:F2)
```

Drag down all your formulas. All cells should be formatted as number with 2 decimal places.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Isolated!! IT WORKED!!

Comment: @VeeGarcia Good to hear, please consider marking as an approved answer, thanks.